# Weird iframe loads src but displays blank in firefox and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm facing a weird issue I can't seem to figure. I'm using an iframe in a scroll box type widget, and it loads fine in Chrome.

However, in firefox the iframe loads but displays blank 80%+ of the time. And in safari, it displays blank until I move over it with my cursor.

What's really driving me crazy is it shows correctly time to time, but has the problem most of the time despite my best efforts.

Any ideas why?

The iframe loads in a corner box that scrolls up about 30% down the page.

Here's the outputted code of the whole scroll box on the page

```
<div id="lf-widget" class="scroll-triggered-box stb stb-bottom-right" style="position: fixed; right: 0px; border-top-width: 7px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: rgb(52, 152, 219); margin-right: 20px; z-index: 9999; visibility: visible; background-size: 50px; padding: 0px !important; background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/asdfasdf/assets/load.gif) !important; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;" data-trigger="percentage" data-trigger-percentage="0">
<iframe allowtransparency="true" src="http://app.asdfdsaf.com/asdfasdf/20/widget/#20?trigger=percentage&amp;trigger-percentage=0" height="319" width="300" style="display: block !important;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="lf-frame"></iframe>
<div class="triangle" id="triangle" style="border-color: #3498db transparent transparent transparent !important; margin-top: -1px;"><p class="inner-triangle">❯</p></div>
<span id="cf-close" class="stb-close">×</span>
</div>
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: You should probably include some code samples of what you have tried already.  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You have  few javascript errors you need to sort out

Comment: Sorry. I initially thought providing a little bit of code wouldn't lead to the right answer, and that having the widget inspected would be more insightful to the answerer. I added the code to my post.

Comment: Can you avoid the iframe? These are the kinds of weird edge case issues that they create.

Comment: Good point, iframes can be unpredictable. Attempting to fix those javascript errors now

Comment: could it be that you don't have permission to put it in an iframe?

Comment: I can't be 100% sure, because of your site's code is minified and it is impossible to confirm, but I've seen this type of behavior when the iFrame is loaded outside the DOM Tree. Are you sure the iFrame is not loaded before it is even visible in the DOM Tree? I've also seen this in Safari, when you load the iFrame and then move it with `inneHTML` to some sort of wrapper element. The code for this looked something like this `parent.innerHTML = "<div>" + parent.innerHTML + "</div>";` So if you have something as stupid as that there, that would cause it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that's exactly what's happening. The scroll box is hidden, the iframe loads, and then when the visitor reaches a certain point on a page (specified by the user of our app), it scrolls up with the loaded iframe. Works great in chrome. Kinda weird in safari and firefox. Are iframes best to not be animated? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
#main_nav ul ul ul {
  top:-150;
}
```

It's not the best solution, but all your menus can be displayed without scrolling down.

A Better solution would be to write a javascript function that sets the `top` value to the negative value of the difference between the top edges of adjacent menus.